# "firebase" is added as a dependency in your project's package.json but it doesn't seem to be installed

Tags: reactjs, react-native

"firebase" is added as a dependency in your project's package.json but it doesn't seem to be installed. Please run "yarn" or "npm install" to fix this issue.

I am getting this error while running react-native on expo-cli locally. I have firebase-7.9.0 and expo- ^40.0.0 in my dependencies still it is showing this error.

Comment: did you run `yarn` or `npm install` after adding it as dependency?

Comment: This refers to same problem and contains possible some solutions: https://giters.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/3781?amp=1

Answer (score 20):

If you are using expo, you are supposed to install firebase using expo.

> expo install firebase

Answer (score 17):

I added `@` before `firebase` and the build worked.

```js
"dependencies": {
    "expo": "~41.0.1",
    "@firebase": "^9.0.0-beta.2",
    ...
  },
```

Comment: This is not valid. Please refer to the [package.json specifications](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#dependencies). Also, the dependencies are not the problem.

Comment: @Shivam welp, it worked when deleting the cache and package.lock didn't ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It would work without the `@` though. You should not really use out-of-spec things like this.

Comment: Although it's not to spec, this is the only solution that has worked thus far. I have no idea how you arrived at this but this hack works until another solution is suggested!
Note: this breaks following npm installs so you have to remove the "@" prior to running it.

Comment: Can't see how this would work reliably, pointing at the `@firebase` folder likely only works if you're not using any `/compat` imports as that's under the `firebase` folder

Comment: I'm having the same issue with an Expo managed app: 

Changing the dependency from ```"firebase": "^9.0.2",``` to ```"@firebase": "^9.0.2",``` or ```"firebase9": "^9.0.2",```
solves the issue when running the app.
But whenever I need to install a new package, I need to switch back to ```"firebase": "^9.0.2",``` otherwise yarn gets confused. Any ideas of a workaround that?

Comment: This also works here, as I need a version greater than Expo one. Any better solution than waiting for Expo 43?