# Firebase modular (v9) incompatible with Expo

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, react-native-firebase

I'm using Expo v42.0.1 and trying to install Firebase v9.0.2 and am unable to do so.

### Issue

From running `expo install firebase`, firebase version 8.2.3 is installed. When changing the `package.json` to use firebase version 9.0.2, I get an error when running the app:

> "firebase" is added as a dependency in your project's package.json but it doesn't seem to be installed. Please run "yarn" or "npm install" to fix this issue.

### What I've tried

1. Running `yarn / npm install`
2. Running `expo install firebase@9.0.2` (which ends up just downloading 8.2.3)

Has anyone seen this before or know why it is happening? I believe it is because Expo v42 is not yet compatible with the [modular version of firebase (v9)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade).

Comment: Did my answer give you information you needed? If so you can mark is as correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

> Has anyone seen this before or know why it is happening? **I believe it is because Expo v42 is not yet compatible with the modular version of firebase (v9).**

But you can make it work with using it like this in you package.json:

```
"@firebase": "^9.0.2",
```

Discussion about this: ["firebase" is added as a dependency in your project's package.json but it doesn't seem to be installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67688853/firebase-is-added-as-a-dependency-in-your-projects-package-json-but-it-doesn?rq=1)

I have used this solution in 2 projects. 1 works perfectly but in another I faced issued where version `firebase@9.0.0-beta.7` works perfectly but in version `firebase@9.0.2` everything but Firestore works
More about it here: [Expo + firebase@9.0.1/9.0.0: @firebase/firestore:, Firestore (9.0.0): Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69102649/expo-firebase9-0-1-9-0-0-firebase-firestore-firestore-9-0-0-could-not)